# What code to prevent repeat numbers in random integer form - MIT App Inventor

Tags: app-inventor

[image: code for the app]

The app works like this: you fling the **sprite** and the sprite starts bouncing from edge to edge on your screen. When the sprite **hits the edge** it should change the image (example of the numbers now: 2 1 1 3 2 3 1 2 2 2 3 ...) but the problem is it can repeat the same number in a row so it's **2** and again **2** but I want them to be random and to not repeat themselves in a row (example how I want them to be: 1 3 2 3 1 3 2 1 2 3 2 3 1 2 1 ...)

This is a video of the app working: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvib3.jpg

Answer (score 1):

> the problem is it can repeat the same number in a row so it's 2 and again 2 but I want them to be random and to not repeat themselves in a row

store the latest random number in a variable and repeat getting a random number if you got the same number as already stored.

Alternatively you can modify this solution to your needs: [How to pick a random item from a list without picking duplicates?](https://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#2removerandom)